# Lua script via SSH with file io operations

Tags: ssh, lua

I am trying to run a script remotely (remote is server B).  When I run the script locally on server A I get the expected results.  When I run the script via SSH from server A to server B, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ssh admin@server.domain.com "lua/rpi.init" 
lua: lua/rpi.init:8: attempt to index upvalue 'logFile' (a nil value) stack traceback:
        lua/rpi.init:8: in function 'logMsg'
        lua/rpi.init:47: in main chunk
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua
local f = assert(io.popen("sudo netstat -a | grep ^tcp[^6] | grep LISTEN | grep [^0-9]22[0-9][0-9]", 'r'))
local ports22 = {}
local logFile

function logMsg(msg)
        logFile = io.open("logs/pi.init.log", "a+")
        logFile:write(os.date("%b %d %Y %X ") .. tostring(msg) .. "\n")
        logFile:close()
end

function getPorts22()
logMsg("Getting available ports...")
while true do
        line = f:read()
        if line == nil then break end
        port = string.sub(line, 40, 44)
        table.insert(ports22, port)
end
f:close()
table.sort(ports22)
end

function getNextOpenPort22()
        local openPort = 2222
        if #ports22 == 0 then
                logMsg("Returning port :" .. openPort)
                return openPort
        end
        for i=1, #ports22 + 1 do
                if tonumber(ports22[i]) == openPort then
                        openPort = openPort + 1
                else
                        logMsg("Returning port: " .. openPort)
                        return openPort
                end
        end

end


function printPorts()
        msg = table.concat(ports22, ", ")
        logMsg("Found ports in use: " .. tostring(msg))
end

logMsg("Script called to run.")
getPorts22()
printPorts()
print(getNextOpenPort22())
```

---

Is it possible to run scripts via SSH (bash, lua or otherwise) and have them perform io operations on the remote machine?

Also, what is the best way to return values from the remote script to the local host?  I return the value from my script by calling print() in order to have something for my local script to actual use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `io.open` calls returns a nil value and an error message. You may need to change this line `logFile = io.open("logs/pi.init.log", "a+")` to something like the following:

```
local logFile, err = io.open("logs/pi.init.log", "a+")
if not logFile then error(err, 2) end
```

This will print the error message when `io.open` call is not successful. In your case it may be caused by non-existent `logs` folder, insufficient permissions, or something else; the error message should point you in the right direction.

Comment: This was perfect.  Turns out when running remotely I need to specify the full path of the log file, relative paths do not work! lua: lua/rpi.init:47: logs/pi.init.log: No such file or directory